# I want to create a simple movie recommendation system with Y(i,j)=ith movie rated by jth user and R(i,j)=1 if a movie has been rated ,else r(i,j)=0

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pymatlab as mat
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io


mat=scipy.io.loadmat('ex8_movies.mat')
Y=mat['Y']
R=mat['R']
plt.interactive(False)
#plt.plot(Y)
#plt.show()

print(Y[R==1])
#print(Y[R==0])

r=tf.constant(R,dtype=tf.float32)
params=scipy.io.loadmat('ex8_movieParams.mat')
num_users = params['num_users']
num_movies =params['num_movies']
num_features=params['num_features']

print("shape of Y:",np.shape(Y))
print(num_users)
print(num_movies)
x=np.random.rand(1682,2)

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,([1682 ,2]))
#X=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1682,943]),dtype=tf.float32)
thetas=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([943,2]),dtype=tf.float32)
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1682 ,943])
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
#print((np.transpose(thetas)))
j_temp=tf.square(tf.matmul(X,tf.transpose(thetas))- y)
j_temp=j_temp([R==1])
cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(j_temp))

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.09).minimize(cost)
sess.run(j_temp,{X:x,y:Y})
#sess.run(j_tmp)
sess.run(cost)

print("slodvhbdfh\n\n")
print(Y[R==0])
```

I want to create a simple movie recommendation system with Y(i,j)=ith movie rated by jth user and R(i,j)=1 if a movie has been rated ,else r(i,j)=0
I am getting the error:

```
"C:\Python\python interpreter\pythonw.exe" C:/Python/Projects/recommend.py

[5 4 4 ..., 2 3 3]
shape of Y: (1682, 943)
[[943]]
[[1682]]

File "C:/Python/Projects/recommend.py", line 38, in <module>
j_temp=j_temp([R==1])
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please provide the sample code you have tried so far

Comment: yeah ,I edited it with sample code

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identifier(arguments)` is the Python syntax for calling a function.  You tried to do this with a tensor, which is *not* a function -- you can't call it.  What are you trying to do?  I can't tell, since you provided no description in text, comments, or even useful variable names.

In addition, the construct `[R==1]' is not legal Python.  If you're trying to get all rated movies for that user, you need to review the syntax to apply a filter to a tensor.  Those keywords should lead you to an answer.